# Not working <title><meta> tag build file in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have created simple dynamic page. If I run it on `localhost`, the `tile` and `meta` tag are working fine. And when I build it, I could not see `title` and `meta` tag in view page source.

Could you please check my code `<title>` and `<meta>` tag part?

`category/[list]/[id].js`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Grid, Image, Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react"
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import Layout from '../../../components/layout'
import Link from "next/link"

const Post = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { Id } = router.query
    console.log(props.category_list)
    return (
        <>
            <Layout>
                <Head>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <title>Welcome to Payments, Deals</title>
                    <meta name="description" content="This is sample content" />
                    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
                    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="rtIRrUNRpgZ_lFtlfS8LJ0-8j_d569BXS9NOGa_nM6Y" />
                </Head>
                <Grid className="store-list">
                    <Grid.Column width={16}>
                        <p>
                            <span>{props.category_title.heading_label}</span>
                        </p>
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
                <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers storeList">
                    {props.category_list.map((x) => {
                        return (
                            <Grid.Column>
                                <Segment>
                                    <Card>
                                        <Link href={"../../store" + "/" + x.name + "/" + x.store_id} passHref={true}>
                                            <a> <Image
                                                src={x.image}
                                                alt=""
                                                className="collection-img"
                                            ></Image>
                                            </a>
                                        </Link>
                                        <Card.Content>
                                            <Link href={"../../store" + "/" + x.name + "/" + x.store_id} passHref={true}>
                                                <a>
                                                    <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                                                </a>
                                            </Link>
                                            <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                                        </Card.Content>
                                        <Card.Content extra>
                                            <p className="rewards">
                                                <span>
                                                    <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                                                </span> Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p className="location">
                                                <span>
                                                    <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                                                </span>
                                                <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                                                {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                                                    <span className="store-location">
                                                    {index === 0 ? (
                                                        <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                                                    ) : index >= 1 ? (
                                                        <span>
                                                        ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                                                        </span>
                                                    ) : null}
                                                    </span>
                                                ))} */}
                                            </p>
                                        </Card.Content>
                                    </Card>
                                </Segment>
                            </Grid.Column>
                        );
                    })}
                </Grid>
            </Layout>
        </>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // change your API url to get ALL categories
    const topMenu = await fetch('https://Sampleapp.ae/api/v5/web/categories', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: "React POST Request Example" }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

    })
    const menus = await topMenu.json();
    const s = menus.categories;
    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts, play with params variable you are returning
    const paths = s.map((post) => ({
        params:
        {
            list: `${post.store_name}`,
            id: `${post.id}`,
        }
    }))

    // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
    // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
    // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const id = context.params.id;
    const postBody = {
        category_id: id,
        offer_type: "",
    };
    const offerList = await fetch('https://simple.ae/api/v5/web/list', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
    const category = await offerList.json();
    // const bookJson = JSON.stringify(book)
    // const bookJson=offerData.stores;
    const category_list = category.stores;
    const category_title = category;
    return {
        props: {
            category_list,
            category_title
        }
    };
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: This code is not enough to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

**Any dom manipulation done using JavaScript will not be visible in the view source.**

**View Source**  simply shows the HTML as it was delivered from the web server to our browser.

Comment: How to show page title and meta tag in nextjs applications.

Comment: @IshanBassi Next.js pre-renders every page on the server, the above code should add the meta tags to the HTML returned to the browser.

Comment: @juliomalves, How to fix pre-render above code my head tag